# Android unit testing Realm

Tags: android, unit-testing, realm

I can't find a solution to do some unit testing on Android. I am trying to test Realm interaction with a service. 
I tried using PowerMockito and in memory solution, but in each case it's not working for me.

I am looking for a solution to check the data stored in realm. Could someone can give me a resource or a hint?

**Edit: My sample code for inMemory**

**build.gradle**

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
...
dependencies {
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
}
```

**Sync Service**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class StateSyncServiceTest {

    lateinit var mockRealm: Realm

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        val testConfig = RealmConfiguration.Builder().inMemory().name("test-realm").build()
        mockRealm = Realm.getInstance(testConfig)
    }

    @Test
    fun shouldBeAbleToGetDefaultInstance() {
        Assert.assertThat(Realm.getDefaultInstance(), `is`(mockRealm)) //NOT WORKING WRONG OBJECT
    }

    @Test
    fun correctSynchronizationPerformed() {
        //given
        val organizationsDTO = listOf<OrganizationDTO>(OrganizationDTO(3, "Organization Mauritius", true))
        val statesDTO = listOf<StateDTO>(StateDTO(2, 3, false, "State 2"), StateDTO(3, 3, false, "State 3"))
        val stateDAO = StateDAO()
        val stateSynchroService = StateSyncService()

        //when
        stateSynchroService.synchronize(statesDTO, organizationsDTO)

        //then
        val resultRealm = stateDAO.findAll()
        Assert.assertEquals(statesDTO.size, resultRealm?.size) //WRONG DATA, MIX PRODUCTION AND TEST
    }
}
```

Plus the data aren't erased from the emulator. I still can get the realm db file with the mix data after execution..

Comment: You could check https://stackoverflow.com/a/35186418/2462531

Comment: what's the problem in setting up inMemory realm, I am presently running androidTest using inMemory realm and it works fine

Comment: By setting it in memory, it's loading some production data, but I am setting the realm database differently in my tests.. I don't get it...

Comment: You will have to insert some test data in your inMemory realm, although I couldn't understand you properly, maybe post some code snippets .

Comment: Use a different configuration with `inMemory`, a different `name()`, and `initialData()`

Comment: I have edited and posted my code.

Comment: seems that you are trying to combine inMemory config with the realm example posted on github :)
Just setup your inMemory realm in @BeforeClass, and store it as a field,  to check `shouldBeAbleToGetDefaultInstance()`, you will first need to set your default instance config using `setDefaultConfiguration()`

Comment: It's not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it, with the help of @Sarthak Mittal.
The init part wasn't working properly.

```
@Before
fun setup() {
    val testConfig = RealmConfiguration.Builder().inMemory().name("test-realm").build()
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(testConfig)
    mockRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
}

@After
@Throws(Exception::class)
public override fun tearDown() {
    mockRealm.close()
}
```